# breaking appended list into indexes

Tags: list, insert, indexing, append

So right now i have code that gives me

[-1], [1], [-1], [-1], [2], [3], [4], [-1], [5], [6], [7], [-1], [-1], [-1], [8], [9], [-1], [-1], [-1], [10]]

but i want it to look like so

myVV = [[-1, 1, -1, -1],[ 2, 3, 4, -1],[5, 6, 7, -1],[-1, -1, 8, 9],[ -1, -1, -1, 10]]

i have a for loop with a inserted line

myVV.append([])

that gives me this

[[], [-1], [1], [-1], [-1], [], [2], [3], [4], [-1], [], [5], [6], [7], [-1], [], [-1], [-1], [8], [9], [], [-1], [-1], [-1], [10]]

it inserts the break were i want the split of indexes to happen.

Any things to read that would help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use mod to check if it's time to add a new [].

```
l = [[-1], [1], [-1], [-1], [2], [3], [4], [-1], [5], [6], [7], [-1], [-1], [-1], [8], [9], [-1], [-1], [-1], [10]]
l2 = []
for i in xrange(len(l)):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        l2.append([])
    l2[i/4].append(l[i][0])

print l2
```

prints

```
[[-1, 1, -1, -1], [2, 3, 4, -1], [5, 6, 7, -1], [-1, -1, 8, 9], [-1, -1, -1, 10]]
```

Comment: im a bit confused on that works, i attained the desired outcome, but could you explain how that works? for future things so I could learn it and understand the logic here.

Comment: @user3772157, `i%4` transform 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,... into 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,..., and `i/4` transform 0,1,2,3,4,5,... into 0,0,0,0,1,1,... These are common patterns used in programming. You just need more practice and will start seeing the same patterns soon.

Comment: How would i use mod to check when to add a new line?

Comment: i sent up a count;however, it not want i wanted because it cause they breaking to happen like in a pattern, i want to achieve [#####][##][#######][#####################] something like that # being numbers of course

Comment: @user3772157, sorry I don't understand your question. Please specify the input and output

Comment: i have this in my code  if tabsplit[1] != middle:
            middle=tabsplit[1]#sets middle to last y value
            placement[0] += 1# in a sense i=i+1            
            placement[1] = 0# casue the reset in j
            myVV.append([])

Comment: the myVV.append[] in the loop give the placement of where i want my breaks [[], [-1], [1], [-1], [-1], [], [2], [3], [4], [-1], [], [5], [6], [7], [-1], [], [-1], [-1], [8], [9], [], [-1], [-1], [-1], [10], [11], [12]]  , SORRY IF I AM NOT MAKING MUCH SENSE

Comment: @user3772157, please edit your post with your complete script and update format. I cannot decipher your script without knowing the indentation

Comment: Sorry, So basically it is the same question as the main one on top the one that you answered so kindly, the only difference is that i want a break in indexes when a term in my file changes and it varies ,so the break could be like [-1 1 ][-1-1 2 3 4] [-1 -1 3]... and so on. when i put myVV.append([]) in an if statement is inserts the [] in the desired location for all breaks. I basically want that. Does that make sense? how would or could i tell the code to break and make it look like you did

Comment: ^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @user3772157, how do we know the sub-lists should have sizes 2, 5, 3, ...?

Comment: well the file that i have has x,y,z coordinates , and every time the y changes that were i want the break to happen

Comment: heres an  0.0 0.0 NaN
1.0 0.0 1.0
2.0 0.0 NaN
3.0 0.0 NaN
0.0 1.0 2.0
1.0 1.0 3.0
2.0 1.0 4.0
3.0 1.0 NaN
0.0 2.0 5.0
1.0 2.0 6.0
2.0 2.0 7.0
3.0 2.0 NaN
0.0 3.0 NaN
1.0 3.0 NaN
2.0 3.0 8.0
3.0 3.0 9.0
0.0 4.0 NaN
1.0 4.0 NaN
2.0 4.0 NaN
3.0 4.0 10.0
3.0 4.0 10.0
3.0 4.0 10.0